# IBM Watson Assistant: Entity (number) extraction in French

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, french

I'm doing the [restaurant tutorial for IBM Watson Assistant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/tutorial-slots.html#add-intent) and I need to extract the number of persons for the reservation.

Since I'm French, I wanted to try this tutorial in French. However, French language being what it is, when you make a reservation for a table in English, there isn't any number in this phrase. But in french, the same phrase gives you "Je voudrai réserver **une table**".

"Une table" can be translated in different ways such as "a table" or... "one table" and this one table is interpreted by Watson Assistant as being the number of persons (even if I said that I would like to reserve a table for 5 people).

I was thinking to tell Waston to take only the second number but since you don't have to add the number of persons in the same phrase and eventually that you could put the number of persons before the "a table", this isn't a good solution.

Is there another solution that would be way better and more importantly would work in a majority of case ?

Comment: Have you tried it? In German we have the same problem, but Watson should be able to learn and to distinguish between guests and tables. In the examples you could provide sentences with "une table" and different number of guests and variations of guest, e.g., persons, people

Comment: Good idea, I will try, thank you very much !

Comment: Ok, so it didn't work (maybe I'm not doing the right thing...) but instead I create an entity for "une table" and it seems to work fine !